# CSS Rotation Glyphicon

Tags: css

I am trying to rotate a glyphicon that's been added :before an a tag. I have tried a lot that doesn't seem to work, but must be missing something simple. The a tag will change from Closed/Open when clicked, which should trigger the animation

```
.Closed:before {
   font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
   content:"\e258";
}

<a class='FolderTitle Closed'>Providers</a>
```

It just needs to rotate 90 degrees and keep it's position - any ideas / JSFiddles?

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: inline-block;` on your pseudo element. After that you'll be able to rotate your content. So your CSS should look like this:

```
.Closed:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e258";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXwoeP)